# PostgreSQL with DataGrip - "table does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

DataGrip is connected to a PostgreSQL database running on localhost.

`DROP TABLE users` returns 'table does not exist'

Dropping the table via the `context menu -> drop` works just fine, checked on another table (which had the same problems). In preview, exactly the same SQL I'm trying to run in the console is shown.

`public.users` yields the same results.

`herokulocal.public.users` yields "cross-database references are not implemented"

Other queries, such as `select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables;` work just fine.

Additionally, `users` is not visible in the results yielded by `select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables;`.

Given that the exact same query generated by WebStorm for `context menu -> drop` does not work in the console, it makes me think my console's running in some different context. Please note I'm a database layman.

What possibly could be wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I connected with a wrong database - `postgres` instead of `herokulocal`.